# Image Source Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I try to make a button image change when it is Pressed, Normal and Disabled, this is my XAML code:

```
 <Button x:Name="Open" Content="Open" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="442,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="20" Click="Open_Click" IsDefault="False" IsEnabled="True">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Image x:Name="Normal" Source="../Resources/o_b.png" Visibility="Visible"/>
                    <Image x:Name="Pressed" Source="../Resources/o_b.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    <Image x:Name="Disabled" Source="../Resources/o_b.png" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Disabled" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

And this is the error i have,

> "Could not find a part of the path 'D:\vs saves\QuickImg\Resources\o_b.png'.

I get this same error at all lines where i try to access the image resources.

**UPDATE:** I solved the problem, I ain't sure what caused this problem but i just deleted the Resources folder and created a new one named Images, added the images and updated the Source in the xaml.

Comment: (Assuming you're looking to improve this question) you've got what you tried and what went wrong (two ticks) but what you're missing here is the context; what were you trying to achieve with this code

Comment: Thanks, I will improve the question when I have time.

Comment: It's hard to improve an old question that I don't even remember.

Comment: I know what you mean, its the only advice I can offer however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I probably did not set o_b.png as resource.